# Custom ordering of variables in the legend of a bar chart

Tags: stata

How do I create a stacked `bar chart` in Stata (v 15.1) in which the `legend` displays the variables in the same order as they are stacked in the chart?

The bars are stacked in this order:

```
variable 4, variable 3, variable 2, variable 1
```

However, the `legend` is in this order:

```
variable 1, variable 2, variable 3, variable 4
```

I would like the order of the variables in the bars to match the order in the `legend`.

Current code:

```
graph bar (asis) supplier customer employee enviro, over(year, lab(angle(90))) stack ///
legend(lab(1 "suppliers") lab(2 "customers") lab(3 "employees") lab(4 "environment")) ///
ti("Articles returned from Factiva search") ///
note("Search term: 'corporate social responsibility' AND '<stakeholder name>'", /// 
size(vsmall)) scheme(plotplainblind)
```

Comment: Use the `order()` suboption of `legend()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please always provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with your question.

Here is a toy example adapted from the [relevant Stata manual](https://www.stata.com/manuals13/g-2graphbar.pdf#g-2graphbarRemarksandexamplesTreatmentofbars):

```
clear

input var4 var3 var2 var1
var4 var3 var2 var1
27.9 21.7 46.1 46.2
end

graph bar (asis) var4 var3 var2 var1, legend(rows(1)) name(graph1, replace)

graph bar (asis) var4 var3 var2 var1, legend(rows(1) order(4 3 2 1)) name(graph2, replace)
```

For more information type `help legend_options` from Stata's command prompt.